# Is it possible to dynamically set multiple Google Sheet Chart Titles based on a dropdown

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a number of tables of data in a single Google Sheet with about 10 charts linked to each table.

Data in one of the tables is dependant on a dropdown list of branch names. This table has about 10 charts linked to it. When a branch is selected from the dropdown, all of the charts linked to this table only, reflect the new information in the table.

I want to make it clearer to users as to what branch each chart relates to. This is an example of one of my simple charts. In this example, I would like the title to read "London Service Failures" or "New York Service Failures" depending on the branch selected in the dropdown next to the table:

[image]

I have this script which works for one chart but it doesn't build the chart with the original criteria e.g. the chart border changes from red to white in every instance.

```js
function onOpen(){
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('Charts').addItem('Update Chart titles', 'updateChartTitles').addToUi();
}
function updateChartTitles() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var value = sheet.getRange("H194").getValue();
  var chart = sheet.getCharts()[9];
  chart = chart.modify()
  .setOption('title', sheet.getActiveCell().getValue()||value) 
  .build();
  sheet.updateChart(chart);
 }
```

The title for this chart is sourced from cell H194 which is a Concatenate formula from the dropdown. I want another 6 charts to source the title from different cells and to be be updated with a single click from the Charts Menu UI.

Is this possible in Google Sheets? Or is there a better method?

Comment: The title of chart on Google Spreadsheet can be modified using the OnEdit event trigger when the dropdown list is changed. But unfortunately, I couldn't understand about your actual situation from `I want the chart title to read "London Purchases" and another to read "London Sales" when "London" is selected in the dropdown list.`. I apologize for my poor English skill.

Comment: I have a table of purchases and sales which changes depending on the branch selected in the dropdown. There is a chart for branch purchases and another chart for branch sales. I, therefore, want the 2 different charts titles to read "London Purchases" and the other to read "London Sales" when "London" is selected in the dropdown list. Alternatively, if Tokyo is selected, I want the 2 different charts titles to read "Tokyo Purchases" and the other to read "Tokyo Sales".

Comment: Thank you for replying. In that case, there are 2 dropdown lists, you want to change the title of a chart when both dropdown lists are changed. If my understanding is correct, I think that it can be achieved using the OnEdit event trigger. But it is required to prepare the script with Google Apps Script.

Comment: Just one dropdown list (branch) for one table of data. There are other tables that don't have a dropdown list but also have charts. I am wanting to change the chart titles on the charts that link to the table with the dropdown list.

Comment: Although I cannot understand about `the charts that link to the table with the dropdown list`, I think that the title of chart can be modified by changing one dropdown list.

Comment: There is a table in the sheet. A dropdown list of branches determines what is in the table. This determines what is in the chart

Comment: Thank you for repling. In that case, at first, it might be required to prepare an object for the coordinate of the dropdownlist and the chart. I think that using this, your goal can be achieved.

Comment: How have you created your chart? It is UI-created or programatically?

Comment: Don't know what that means. Just highlighted the table and went from there

Comment: Is it a specific chart you want to change the title of or all? Can you provide an example output?

Comment: I have reworded the question slightly and added an example of one of my simple charts

Comment: https://support.google.com/docs/forum/AAAABuH1jm0_gWVent33eA/?hl=en&gpf=%23!topic%2Fdocs%2F_gWVent33eA%3Bcontext-place%3Dforum%2Fdocs

Comment: How are your charts identified? You can get a list of your charts programmatically but is it all of them or just one you want to change?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "How are your charts identified?". There are 15 charts in the sheet and there are 7 linked to the table with the dropdown that I want to have the dynamic chart title.